# I want to increase my home or switch partitions

Tags: ubuntu, gparted

As you can see I made a mistake partitioning my hard drive. Currently dual booting windows 10/ubuntu my current home is only 10gb. How can I resize this?

[image]

Comment: Boot with Gparted Live and resize as needed. Don't forget to do a backup first.

Comment: Only use Windows to resize NTFS partitions, reboot Windows & run chkdsk after any NTFS resize, and then Ubuntu live installer or gparted live to edit Linux partitions. But you do not have a lot of extra room anywhere. Windows NTFS really likes 30% free and at 10% free, you just about cannot run a defrag as you have no working room. Linux needs some room but not quite as much. Time to houseclean or consider new larger drive.

Comment: @oldfred thanks

Comment: Pity about that extended partition. A GPT partition table would be more flexible. Something to bear in mind when you next partition a disk.

Answer (score 0):

Resize is an easy task in Linux.
There are many tools for this purpose.

You can easily use `gparted`as you show in the screenshot but again you can't currently on-the-fly perform the operation because your $HOME partition is in use; *gparted* shows a padlock on the left...
The further step you need is to reboot your PC in a live environment and **then** use *gparted*